# Internet Explorer wrong height

Tags: css

I have a `td` styled with CSS like this:

```
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  color:#FFF;
  width:100%;
}
table td{
  border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
  vertical-align:top;
  text-align:left;
  padding:0px;
}
.tbs{
  font-weight:bold;
  height:20px;
}
.tbs a{
  color:#B8B6B4;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.tbs a.act{
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background-color:#1E1E1E;
}
.tbs a:hover{
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

`.tbs` is the `td`, on Firefox it's all good, but on IE, even if it's **explicitly** declared height to 20px it shows me a height of 28.5px, why this? I could understand this if I omitted height, but it's declared, what can I do to fix it, is there a CSS only solution without editing the structure?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I'm adding a Jsfiddle, even if I think it's useless, cause most of my code don't work...
http://jsfiddle.net/2TZ2Z/

Comment: Can you add your HTML or even if you create fiddle would be great

Comment: Please always create a fiddle or post your complete code to allow for a more full overview of your issue with greater ease.

Comment: Maybe add `line-height: 20px;` as well.

Comment: What version of IE are you dealing with?

Comment: @putvande It's no use...